# Edit form data using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a Chrome extension to edit specific values in form data.
This is my current code for background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if(details.method == "POST") {
      let formData = details.requestBody.formData;
      if(formData) {
        Object.keys(formData).forEach(key => {
          formData[key].forEach(value => {
            if(key.includes("name")) {
              formData.name = "John";
              details.requestBody.formData = formData;
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
    return {details: details};
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["requestBody"]
);
```

When I tried to debug it I came to conclusion that the extension can successfully edit `formData`, but the server will still receive the unedited `formData`.
I think the problem might be with returning `details`.

Comment: Not implemented, see https://crbug.com/91191. You'll have to spoof XHR/fetch in the [page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: How could I do that. I've looked at many examples none seem to work. @wOxxOm

Comment: Use any example that overrides XMLHttpRequest and put that code in a script element as shown in the answer I've linked.